# F#: how to calculate a subset using filtering predicate?

Tags: filter, f#, set, seq

E.g.
For integer numbers between 1 and 10, select 3 numbers that:

```
1. Sum of these 3 numbers equals to 24
2. These 3 numbers could build a right triangle.
```

How to use F# to get these 3 numbers?
I know for Haskell this is very simple:

```
Prelude> let rightTriangle=[(a,b,c)|c<-[1..10],a<-[1..c],b<-[1..a],a^2+b^2==c^2,a+b+c==24]
Prelude> rightTriangle
```

The solution is

```
[(8,6,10)]
```

I'm not sure if

```
F# could help to generate a Cartesian product conveniently?
F# could add different filter conditions inside one expression?
```

So, how to implement it with F# conveniently?
Thanks.

Comment: Look up F# cartesian product here.  Then use List.filter

Comment: Here's a [sample code](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/a212fa71c9bd1166a102849726c1f5ef7450d97c/FsControl.Core/Samples/Collections.fsx#L270) similar to that Haskell solution, using FsControl.

Comment: Also, what exactly is the problem - we are not a free haskell -> F# translation service

Comment: Where is your attempted solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct equivalent of the Haskell version in F# would be to use list comprehensions:

```
let rightTriangle=
  [for c in 1 .. 10 do
   for a in 1 .. c do
   for b in 1 .. a do
     if pown a 2 + pown b 2 = pown c 2 && a + b + c = 24 then
       yield a, b, c ]
```

Generally speaking, F# comprehensions are closer to "normal F# language" rather than being a special language feature (if you drop the `[` .. `]` around it, it looks almost like imperative iteration using loops).

- The `for` construct corresponds to `a <- 1 .. 10`, but you need to nest multiple fors if you want to bind multiple variables
- The `if` construct corresponds to the filtering using the `==` bit in Haskell
- The `yield` specifies what values should be returned from the list comprehension

Comment: So you mean, F# comprehensions is not so powerful and convenient(from math point of view) like Haskell? Then what's the advantage of F# against Haskell, except it's built on .net and work with C#? Other advantages of F# comparing with Haskell? Thanks.